# Problemas con la conexion a la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy realizando un cambio en los diferentes registros, que estan asociados con un numero de servicio que es la primary key pero al momento de realizar el cambio me muestra este error:

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Pruebas\conexion.php on line 17

conexion.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
class MySQL {  
    private $conexion;
    private $servicio_No;  
    private $total_consultas;  
    public function MySQL() {  
        if(!isset($this->conexion)) {  
            $this->conexion = (mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin123","database")) or die(mysqli_error()); 
        }  
    }  

    public function consulta($consulta){  
        $this->total_consultas++;  
        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion,$consulta);  
        if(!$resultado){  
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();  
            exit;  
        }  

        return $resultado;   
    } 

    public function fetch_array($consulta){   
        return mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);  
    } 

    public function num_rows($consulta){   
        return mysqli_num_rows($consulta);  
    }  

    public function getTotalConsultas(){  
        return $this->total_consultas;  
    }  
}
?>
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function agregar () {
            if ( document.frm.txtEtiqueta.value.length == 0 ) {
                alert("Debes escribir algo");
            } else {
                var nuevoItem = document.frm.txtEtiqueta.value;
                var combo = document.getElementById("situacion");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                combo.options.add(option, 0);
                combo.options[0].value = nuevoItem;
                combo.options[0].innerText = nuevoItem;
                document.frm.txtEtiqueta.value = "";
            }
        }

        function eliminar() {
            var combo = document.getElementById("situacion");
            combo.remove(document.getElementById("situacion").selectedIndex);
        }

        function modificar() {
            if ( document.frm.txtEtiqueta.value.length == 0 ) {
                alert("Debes escribir algo");
            } else {
                eliminar();
                agregar();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frm" method="post" action="recibe.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Situacion :</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <select name="situacion" id="situacion">
                        <option>Finalizado</option>
                        <option>Fallido</option>
                        <option>Cancelado</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Servicio No :</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" name="servicio_No" id="servicio_No" placeholder="Numero del servicio">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Valor:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtEtiqueta" /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="agregar();" value="Agregar item" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="eliminar();" value="Eliminar item seleccionado" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="modificar();" value="Modificar item seleccionado por caja de texto" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
</body>
```

recibe.php

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$servicio_No = $_POST['servicio_No'];
$situacion = $_POST['situacion'];
$db = new MySql();
$query = "INSERT INTO servicio(servicio_No,situacion) VALUES ('$servicio_No','$situacion')";
$consulta = $db->consulta($query);
echo "Se inserto en la base de datos el valor de <b>$situacion</b><br>";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Regresar</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Veo que josto te dieron la respuesta. Igualmente indicar que ti codigo es **VULNERABLE A INYECCION SQL**

Comment: aun no funciona

Comment: Son 2 problemas distintos. El error que te da es por lo que te he dicho. Aparte tienes un problema en tu query

Comment: Tambien indicar que la forma antigua de constructores con el mismo nombre que la clase esta obsoleto, en su lugar se deberia utilizar `__construct`. ¿Que error obtienes ahora?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Pruebas\conexion.php on line 17

Comment: cuando quito la variable servicio_No funciona pero no actuliza el servicio indicado

Comment: Cuando creas la conexion estas utilizando `mysqli_error()`  y es `mysqli_connect_error()`. Deberias obtener el error que produce la consulta y/o la conexion con mysql corriguiendo esto y lo que te indica el compañero.

Comment: corrigiendo me muestra el error que puse

Comment: El error creo que esta asociado por el servicio_No

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris Corregiste lo del constructor como te indique antes??

Comment: en que parte corrijo los constructores?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79033/discussion-between-xerif-and-cristian-antonio-trujillo-gris).

Answer (score 0):

Te falta poner la conexion en el `mysqli_error`

```
mysqli_error($this->conexion)
```

[Fuente](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)

PD: Obviamente la query falla.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Pruebas\conexion.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined property: MySQL::$ in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Pruebas\conexion.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Pruebas\conexion.php on line 17

Comment: No es necesario, eso es opcional

Comment: Muestra mas errores

Comment: @AlfredoPaz no es opcional, mira la documentacion.